# how to copy an object without changing the orignial - java

Tags: java, object, copy

I'm quite a beginner in java. While writing a code for a little project I stumbled upon a problem which after many tries I still wasn't able to solve.
I got a small class which only stores a 2d-array:

```
class Board{
    int[][] Field;

    Board(int[][] field){
      Field=field;
    }

    Board(Board Test){
      this.Field=Test.Field;
    }

    public void change(int x, int y, int number){
      Field[y][x]=number;
    }

    public void Print(){
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[0]);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[1]);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[2]);
    }
}
```

My intention is the following:

1. Create an object Test1 with a testarray.
2. Create an object Test2 which has an independent copy ob the testarray from Test1.
3. Change something on the testarray of Test2.

I tried this with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[][] testarray={ {0,0,0},
                      {0,0,0},
                      {0,0,0}};

  Board Test1=new Board(testarray);    //creates the object Test1 with the testarray
  Board Test2=new Board(Test1);        //creates the object Test2 with the object Test 1 as model
  Test2.change(1,1,1);                 //changes something on the array of Test 2
  Test2.Print();                       //prints the array of Test2
  Test1.Print();                       //prints the array of Test1 
}
```

But when I execute the code, the array of the object Test1 is changed on the exact same way as I changed the array of the object Test 2! I've already searched on this forum and found many similar post. There are also various ideas how to solve this, but I tried many of them (as use the method clone(), or arraycopy() etc.)  and none of them works for my problem (or I was just stupid). As I have read, the problem is probably the "this" statement. I would be really really grateful if anyone could come up with a bit of code, which can copy my object without changing the original one!

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case of how to do a deep copy of an object and that's where JAVA serialization comes handy. You can use Object serialization to save the state of an object and retrieve it later at any point of time. Follow the [link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-deep-clone-using-serializable.html) for more details.

What you need to do is to mark your class as serializable by implementing a marker interface `Serializable`.

```
class Board implements Serializable {
.........
 ...........
  }
```

Write an extra method on how to save and retrieve the object. You can get code from the given link. This will give you exact copy of your object with values saved in the array. You can later modify it according to your need.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! Learned something new today. :)

Comment: Thanks @LukasF. glad to see such a response.

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy(...)` should work but it was designed for 1D arrays, so you will need to iterate on the first dimension of the array. Same issue with `clone`, which doesn't clone underlying objects (or arrays).

The following may help:

```
Board(Board Test){
    this.Field = new int[Test.Field.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < Test.Field.length; i++) {
        this.Field[i] = new int[Test.Field[i].length];
        System.arraycopy(Test.Field[i], 0, this.Field[i], 0, Test.Field[i].length);
    }
}
```

If pure perf is not (yet) an issue, nesting 2 for loops may make the code easier to read instead of using `System.arraycopy(...)`:

```
Board(Board Test){
    this.Field = new int[Test.Field.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < Test.Field.length; i++) {
        this.Field[i] = new int[Test.Field[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < Test.Field[i].length; j++) {
            this.Field[i][j] = Test.Field[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must copy rows AND columns.

```
Board(int[][] field){
  Field=copyField(field);
}

Board(Board Test){
    Field = copyField(Test.Field);
}

private int[][] copyField(int[][] src) {
    if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(src)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("src is empty");
    }
    int[][] dest = new int[src.length][src[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src[i].length; j++) {
            dest[i][j] = src[i][j];
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.arraycopy(..)` in constructor `Board(Board Test)`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board {

    int[][] Field;

    Board(int[][] field) {
        Field = field;
    }

    Board(Board Test) {
        this.Field = new int[Test.Field.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < Test.Field.length; i++) {
            this.Field[i] = new int[Test.Field[i].length];
            System.arraycopy(Test.Field[i], 0, this.Field[i], 0, Test.Field[i].length);
        }
    }

    public void change(int x, int y, int number) {
        Field[y][x] = number;
    }

    public void Print() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[0]));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[1]));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Field[2]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] testarray = {{0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0}};

        Board Test1 = new Board(testarray);
        Board Test2 = new Board(Test1);

        Test2.change(1, 1, 1);
        System.out.println("Test-1-----");

        Test1.Print();

        System.out.println("Test-2-----");
        Test2.Print();
    }

}
```